# XCode: Possible to specify CFBundleIdentifier per-build-configuration?

Tags: xcode, xcode4, build-automation

I just can't figure out how to do this.

I have a special Build Configuration alongside `Debug` and `Release`.  (Let's call it `Foo`)

My `CFBUndleIdentifier` is `com.my-company.our-project`.

However, when I build (and archive) for the `Foo` configuration, I want to use the bundle identifier `com.my-company.foo.our-project`

Is this possible?  Everything I've tried has failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I spend much of my day building a white-label product, so I have to do this all the time.

The solution we came up with was to use an Xcode "Run Script" build phase as a "postflight" script.

In your project file, select the target, Build Phases, and then add a new "Run Script" build phase. I renamed the phase to "postflight" and ensured to move the phase to be the last thing done amongst all the build phases.

The essential thing the postflight script does is look for the built .app package, look for the Info.plist within it, and then change the `CFBundleIdentifier` within it for whatever our present build configuration is set for. Our script does a lot more than just this (other logic, post-processing, resource manipulations, etc.).

I can't provide too many specifics since my setup is customized for me, and yours is obviously customized for you. But that's the basic approach. Hopefully it'll work for you.

Comment: Thanks.  What I forgot to specify is that I need to sign the app with a different Certificate.  So the certificate for `com.my-company.our-project` can't be used to sign ann app with the bundle ID ```com.my-company.foo.our-project```  Suggestions?

Comment: We do that too. Take a look at this [iOS Automated Builds with Xcode4](http://www.splinter.com.au/ios-automated-builds-with-xcode4/). We don't do precisely what he does, but I based a lot of what our script does around that.

Comment: Ah -- so it sounds though like this isn't something I can accomplish without leaving XCode.  Too bad :)   Thanks for the reply!